# How to add system SIP account

Tags: android

From android version 2.3 native VoIP support has become available. How can I add system SIP account from my application? I think solution may be in using System settings content provider. But I dont know how exactly make it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no System content Provider available for SIP account.

There are only two way available for that,

*First,*

You can call **SIP account system activity** through intent.

```
if (SipManager.isVoipSupported(this) && SipManager.isApiSupported(this)){
       // SIP is supported, let's go!
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
       intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.phone/.sip.SipSettings"));
       startActivity(intent);
}
```

*Second,*

You can Register SIP account for specific time period using **[android.net.sip.SipManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html%22android.net.sip.SipManager%22)** class.

If you want more clarification than you can ask me right here...!!!