# Add SIP Account Programmatically

Tags: android, sip

In my app, SIP registration was successfully done,but when i am checking in my phone weather account is added or not, account is added but when i am clicking on that then popup appears with two option:
1.Close Profile
2.Cancel

So there may be account not successfully added.So please suggest me to solve this issue.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191547/how-to-add-system-sip-account) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001463/android-create-sip-account-programmatically) if you're okay w/launching the native sip-settings dialog and then reading the settings out afterwards. You could also do as another user suggested and use a service.

See the official [Android SIP API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html) for the latest, in case such an option has become available.